# Bootstrap Single page Layout Left right scrollable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout

I am trying to design single page layout using bootstrap that has header, footer, left and right.

I designed using Html Div's, but i am unable make it work using bootstrap...

### **Header**

Left (auto scrollable) | Right (auto scrollable)

---

**Footer**

Comment: Not enough info. Make a jsfiddle with your code or at least post some code. Most pages are designed with html div's usually...

Comment: I made fiddle what i am talking about, it used plain HTML, but same thing i am trying to acheive using bootstrap, for some reason the scrollbars are not appearing also the content shifts down when the page shrinks.                           http://jsfiddle.net/nk609423/4FJD8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is kind of vague. However from my understanding your looking for something similar to this type of split page that scrolls with bootstrap columns? If so then check out this Bootply example (http://www.bootply.com/5l9bZ7ZOt6). From there you can create your own headers, footers, and so on.

Contrary to that idea, if you meant that you want to create a simple bootstrap page then check out the documentation and examples listed on the actual site. (http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples)